# Tikz block with multiple arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a simple diagram that requires multiple arrows for its inputs and outputs but I can't figure out how to place the arrows to somewhere other than the center of the block. Is there a straightforward way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: You can start with `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw,minimum width=2cm},font=\sffamily,>=latex]
 \node[draw,rounded corners, minimum size=pi*1cm] (N) {Network};
 \node[left=of N,yshift=-1cm] (A){A};
 \node[left=of N,yshift=1cm] (D){D};
 \draw[->] (A.east) -- (A-|N.west);
 \draw[<-] (D.east) -- (D-|N.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using comment of Schrödinger's cat as starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 8mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum width=12mm, font=\sffamily},
   arr/.style = {draw=blue!60, -{Triangle[fill=blue!60]}}, 
                        ] 
\node (N) [N,rounded corners=2mm, minimum size=24mm]    {Network}; 
\node (a) [N, above left=of N.south west]  {A}; 
\node (d) [N, below left=of N.north west]  {D}; 
\node (b) [N, above right=of N.south east] {B};
\node (c) [N, below right=of N.north east] {C};
\draw[arr]  (a) edge (a -| N.west) 
            (d -| N.west) edge (d)
            (b -| N.east) edge (b)
            (c)  to  (c -| N.east);
\coordinate[right=of b] (aux);
\draw[arr]  (b) -- (aux) |- (c);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]